# What is the consenus of IntechOpen, open access books, are they predatory?

Tags: open-access, disreputable-publishers

I have received an unsolicited request to write a chapter for a book relevant to my research. I have searched the current editors and they are actual people but not very well known in the field. On their website they show various logos, including web of science.

They do not seem to ask any money, but I see that sometimes go Intechopen was listed in the predatory editors. Is it still the case? Or is it because it is an open access editor that big publishers are trying to work against it?

Comment: From what I heard, Intechopen charge authors for publication. I also receive invitations from they every week.

Comment: *"I have received an unsolicited request to write a chapter"* You have your answer right there.

Comment: @NikeyMike That is standard for all gold open access publications and nothing specific to IntechOpen. IEEE, frontiers, PLOS, pick whichever you want, they all charge you to pay for their operations.

Comment: I have noticed the " IntechOpen " is in the list of predatory publishers (https://predatory-publishing.com). This publisher has a questionable reputation in the academic world . Therefore, do not waste your time sending them your works or paying them money for publication.

Comment: Can a request be solicited? How could I ask someone to ask me for something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, IntechOpen is a disreputable publisher.  Do not send them your work or pay them money.

Comment: Which evidence is this answer based on? I have read quite a few reports of very thorough review and editing processes and rejections. People who actually authored for them generally seem to be happy with the process. I actually have not read a single report of someone who actually worked with them being *un*happy with the process, except for people who were surprised that they had to pay something. The fact that they charge money does not make them disreputable or anything, it's a necessary part of open access publishing.

Comment: @jhin Extensive experience with colleagues who publish.  I do not have any competent colleagues who are willing to submit work to this publisher.

Comment: ... but is it because they have had actual bad experiences or because they have heard from yet other colleagues that they consider IntechOpen disreputable? :-) From what I understand, there's also quite a difference between a publisher being *predatory* and being *disreputable*, or am I mistaken? I certainly have the impression that Intech has a bad reputation in the community (your answer being a point in case), but I have yet to find out why exactly that is and whether it has anything to do with them being *predatory*.